# PHP OOP Config Class

Tags: php, config

I have a little problem. I have make a config class which automaticlly return the value that i want.

usage example:

```
echo Config::get('database.host');
```

This returns localhost.

But if i have multiple vars then it returns the first i selected.

example:

```
echo Config::get('database.host');
echo Config::get('database.username');
echo Config::get('database.password');
echo Config::get('database.name');
```

all returns localhost.

here is my config class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

class Config
{
  private static $_config;

  public static function set($config)
  {
    self::$_config = $config;
  }

  public static function get($var = null)
  {
    $var = explode('.', $var);

    foreach ($var as $key) {
      if (isset(self::$_config[$key])) {
        self::$_config = self::$_config[$key];
      }
    }

    return self::$_config;
  }

  public function __destruct()
  {
    self::$_config = null;
  }
}

?>
```

i initialisate it like this:

```
Config::set($config);
```

the $config variable contains my entire config file:

```
 <?php

 $config = [
    'database' => [
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'name'     => 'dev',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '1234'
  ]
];

?>
```

Hope you can help me guys :)
(Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yeah. The first time you call `get()`, you destroy all the other config options:

```
Config::set($config); // sets your nested array
Config::get('foo.bar');
     self::$_config = self::$_config['foo'];
           ^^^^^^^^--overwrite this
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^---with the foo sub value
     self::$_config = self::$_config['bar'];
           ^^^^^^^^--overwrite the previous foo value
                              ^^^^^^^---with bar's
```

Then the next time you call get(), you're not accessing your original `$_config` array. you're accessing whatever value was retrieved with the LAST get() call.

You need to use a temp variable, e.g.

```
Config::get('foo.bar')

   explode ...
   $temp = self::$_config;
   foreach(... as $key) {
      $temp = $temp[$key];
   }
   return $temp;
```